# React Native Pass Index to Props

Tags: react-native, react-modal

I have a modal that contain icons and description and status, and i want to pass the icons and descriptions from index to the modal,I already pass the status. is there anyway to do that? sorry i'm still new to react native and thanks in advance

this is my index.js

```js
export const img =
{
   itemStatus: {
        "Open": { name: 'open-book', type: 'entypo', color: '#ffb732', desc:'New Attribut, New Attention'},
        "Approved": { name: 'checklist', type: 'octicon', color: '#3CB371', desc:'Approved by SPV/MNG' },
        "Escalated": { name: 'mail-forward', type: 'font-awesome', color: '#ffb732', desc:'Escalated to SPV/MNG' },
        "Deliver Partial": { name: 'arrange-send-to-back', type: 'material-community', color: '#8B4513', desc:'Some items in a DO have not arrived/was faulty' },
    
    };
```

and this is my container

```js
class MyRequest extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentStatus: null,
      refreshing: false,
      fetchStatus: null
    };
    
      handleShowModal = (status) =>{
      this.setState({
        currentStatus: status,
      });
  }

  handleDismissModal = () =>{
    this.setState({currentStatus: null});
  }
  
  <View style={[styles.panelContainer, status === 'success' ? {} : { backgroundColor: color.white }]}>
              <FlatList
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                progressViewOffset={-10}
                refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}
                onMomentumScrollEnd={(event) => event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y === 0 ? this.onRefresh() : null}
                data={content}
                renderItem={({ item }) => item}
                keyExtractor={(item, key) => key.toString()}
                 />
            </View>
            <IconModal visible={this.state.modalVisible} close={this.handleDismissModal} icon={} status={this.state.currentStatus} desc={} />
  
    }
```

and this is my modal

```js
const IconModal = (props) => {

    return(
        <Modal 
            isVisible={props.visible}
            onBackdropPress={props.close}
        >
            <View style={styles.dialogBox}> 
                <View style={styles.icon}>
                    <Icon>{props.icon}</Icon>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.text}>
                    <Text style={styles.status}>{props.status}</Text>
                    <Text>{props.desc}</Text>
                </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.close}>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>GOT IT</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear how you plan on mapping against `img.itemStatus` index but you can just reference the object you want as such.

```
import img from '....path_to_index.js'

...

// const currentItemStatus = img.itemStatus.Open
// OR
const itemStatus = 'Open' // Or 'Approved', 'Escalated', 'Deliver Partial' 
const currentItemStatus = img.itemStatus[itemStatus]

...

<IconModal
  visible={this.state.modalVisible}
  close={this.handleDismissModal}
  icon={currentItemStatus.name} // Passing name
  status={this.state.currentStatus}
  desc={currentItemStatus.desc} // Passing desc
/>

...
```

Hope this was helpful

Comment: cana i do like const itemStatus =['Open', 'Approved']

Comment: because i want it to show based on icon i was clicking

Comment: Well it wouldn't work in the example above as `img.itemStatus[itemStatus]` is if you want to dynamically grab the itemStatus you need  (you can only reference by a string). If you wanted to grab multiple items you could also do that but that would be a seperate issue.

Comment: oh ok, could you tell me how to do that because i'm really new to this